# Angular ui-router, how to get state associated with controller?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Plunkr demonstrating problem:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Czc5kGpCwsruUQe2EanZ?p=preview

With the states:

```
.state('state1', {
  url: '/state1',
  template: '<div>state1 <pre>{{current | json }}</pre><div ui-view=""></div> </div>',
  controller: 'State1Ctrl',
})
.state('state1.list', {
  url: '/list',
  template: '<div>list <pre>{{current | json }}</pre></div>',
  controller: 'State1ListCtrl',
})
```

And the controllers:

```
.controller('State1Ctrl', function($scope, $state, $rootScope, $controller) {
  $scope.current = $state
})

.controller('State1ListCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
  $scope.current = $state
})
```

Produces the result:

```
state1
{
  "url": "/list",
  "template": "<div>list <pre>{{current | json }}</pre></div>",
  "controller": "State1ListCtrl",
  "name": "state1.list"
}

list
{
  "url": "/list",
  "template": "<div>list <pre>{{current | json }}</pre></div>",
  "controller": "State1ListCtrl",
  "name": "state1.list"
}
```

When going **directly** to the `state1.list` state.

**I need access to the state that the controller is associated with, e.g. I want the result to be:**

```
state1 (notice how this is different - it has the state1 configuration now)
{
  "url": "/state1",
  "template": "<div>list <pre>{{current | json }}</pre></div>",
  "controller": "State1Ctrl",
  "name": "state1"
}

list
{
  "url": "/list",
  "template": "<div>list <pre>{{current | json }}</pre></div>",
  "controller": "State1ListCtrl",
  "name": "state1.list"
}
```

**I understand that state.$current is the current state, but how do you determine the state that the controller is associated with?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controllers are meant to be independent of state in ui-router, so that the same controller could be used for any state.

But you can get any state from anywhere by using e.g. `$state.get('state1.list')`

I think you may just have to have someone somewhere know which controller is associated with which state. Whether each controller knows which state its associated with and calls `$state.get('stateName')` to get it, or you could build a service which will return the state for a controller name, or you could even use `$state.get()` to get all states and then enumerate through the list until one has a controller name that matches the controller that you are in.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes this does! I was mainly looking for if there was a built-in way but your suggested approaches are good. :)